# How to query names from a record with multiple IDs in LINQ

Tags: linq, join, one-to-many

I have a table [A] that has columns such as CreatedBy(ID), AuthorizedBy(ID), SentTo(ID) and I need to join them to a table [B] containing user names (UserID, FullName). How can I write a join that connects each record of table A to multiple records in table B to fill in the CreatedBy/AuthorizedBy/SentTo names using LINQ?

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: You could add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can give try as below , basically you have to join B with A three times

```
form a in A
 join b in B on b.Id = a.Createdby
 join b1 in B on b1.Id = a.Authrizedby
 join b2 in B on b2.Id = a.SentTo
select new {
   a.Id,
   CreatedBy= b.FullName,
   AuthorizedBy = b1.FullName,
   SentTo=  b2.FullName};
```

or

```
   from a in A 
   select new {
   a.ID
   CreatedBy= b.FirstOrDefault(a.CreatedBy== b.Id).FullName,
   AuthorizedBy = b.FirstOrDefault(a.AuthorizedBy== b.Id).FullName,
   SentTo= b.FirstOrDefault(a.SentTo== b.Id).FullName
   }
```